# How to stop swipe in ScrollView?

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

[look this video of current scrolling behavior](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jdv_VsQlKzD5BaEyUZK6ook-yY9lLhiy). i want, as soon as finger is lifted from screen, to disable scrolling.

Edit: the video shows a user scrolling through a list. When the finger is lifted from the screen, you see the scrolling continues up or down for a short time.

Comment: Added an explanation of the video. This way, readers don't have to leave this page to understand what you're looking for. Also, if the video is unavailable for some reason, people still can understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```js
<ScrollView
  bounces={false}
  />
```

This way when you scroll finished, the scroll animation will not continue and immediately stopped.

Comment: @Va, I have tested, it doesn't help, actually, I trying to fix little another problem, pls look the video drive.google.com/open?id=15hHKWDiilLf-FG1zUO3OOWjd677nz2Fk the scroll should occuring one by one item, you will see that when I quickly scroll it scrolling to the wrong item and then come back to right item

Comment: I saw your video, it looks like it's not about `ScrollView`, it's likely about the View Pager library you use.

Comment: now I use FlatList for it, and thank you, it can be that one I'm searching

Comment: I have been searching View Pager and there all are horizontal oriented, do you know on tath is vertical oriented?

Comment: Although I haven't use it by myself, there is one I know https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vertical-view-pager

Comment: I have already used it, and there the same animation problem with quick swipe, the module use scrollView as and I

Comment: Open source projects are provided by helpful people, with no quality guarantee. You can modify it by yourself, or start a question to ask for one =)

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you want is basically to stop the scroll when momentum beings. For that, you can use the `onMomentumScrollBegin` callback on your ScrollView and call `.scrollToEnd({animated: false})` on it.

Here's how that would look:

```
<ScrollView
  ref={(ref) => this.scrollView = ref}
  scrollEnabled={this.state.scroll}
  onMomentumScrollBegin={
    () => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: false})
  }
 >
   ...CONTENT HERE...
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I need to disable scroll of swipe. If I scrolling and hold finger on screen the scroll should be available, only when I have raised up finger scroll should not continue

Comment: @АндрейШостик That is what the above functionality does. Have you tried it? Did it not work?

Comment: I have tested, it doesn't help, little scrolling present and then it makes scrollToEnd, actually I trying to fix little another problem, pls look the video https://drive.google.com/open?id=15hHKWDiilLf-FG1zUO3OOWjd677nz2Fk the scroll should occuring one by one item, you will see that when I quickly scroll it scrolling to the wrong item and then come back to right item

Answer (score 1):

i think u mean stop scrolling once user lifts his finger
try :

```
<ScrollView 
  ...

  decelerationRate = {0}
  />
```

[check docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview/#decelerationrate)